# Union different column in one and then order by this

Tags: mysql, sql

after a simple query...

```
SELECT Col_ID, datetime1, datetime2, datetime3 
FROM TABLE_DATETIME 
WHERE datetime1 LIKE '20130805%'
    OR datetime2 LIKE '20130805%' 
    OR datetime3 LIKE '20130805%'
```

... I have this scenario

```
Col_ID    |datetime1     |datetime2     |datetime3     |
----------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
40302025  |20130805123022|NULL          |NULL          |
40302028  |20130805180055|NULL          |NULL          |
40302030  |NULL          |20130805090055|NULL          |
40302055  |NULL          |20130805190055|NULL          |
40302074  |NULL          |NULL          |20130805070055|
```

Now, in the same previous query, I want to merge the datetime1, datetime2, datetime3 in one columns which we will call "ALL_DATETIME" then order by this to have this results...

```
Col_ID    |ALL_DATETIME  |
----------|--------------|
40302074  |20130805070055|
40302030  |20130805090055|
40302025  |20130805123022|
40302028  |20130805180055|
40302055  |20130805190055|
```

Comment: use tsql code to achieve this

Comment: You Have error in first Query `OR datetime2 LIKE '20130805%'` should be `OR datetime3 LIKE '20130805%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function for this:

```
SELECT Col_ID
     , COALESCE(datetime1,datetime2,datetime3) AS ALL_DATETIME 
FROM TABLE_DATETIME
WHERE ...
ORDER BY COALESCE(datetime1,datetime2,datetime3)
```

Output:

```
|   COL_ID |   ALL_DATETIME |
-----------------------------
| 40302074 | 20130805070055 |
| 40302030 | 20130805090055 |
| 40302025 | 20130805123022 |
| 40302028 | 20130805180055 |
| 40302055 | 20130805190055 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3430a/8)

Comment: Yeah... I have just learned a new function.
Very very thank... the result is that... 5 records

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULL` handling function

```
SELECT Col_ID, ifnull(datetime1, ifnull(datetime2, datetime3 )) as ALL_DATETIME 
FROM TABLE_DATETIME 
WHERE datetime1 LIKE '20130805%'
OR datetime2 LIKE '20130805%' 
OR datetime3 LIKE '20130805%'
order by 2
```

Comment: Sorry Sorry Sorry it was my fault. Sorry to echo_Me and jaczes. was the heat of the summer to make me wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT Col_ID, greatest (coalesce(datetime1,0), coalesce(datetime2,0),coalesce( datetime3,0) ) alldatetime
FROM TABLE_DATETIME 
WHERE datetime1 LIKE '20130805%'
OR datetime2 LIKE '20130805%' 
OR datetime3 LIKE '20130805%'
```

[**DEMO here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3430a/12)

Comment: @OscarZarrus it was a mistake from you and i followed it :) you have done `OR datetime2` two times :) , ok i updated answer and now its 5 results :9